# NSString string extension does not work

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I was trying out the GTMNSString+XML.h string extension for the following.

```
NSString *value = @"some text";
NSString *newString = [value gtm_stringBySanitizingAndEscapingForXML];
```

However, this crashes with an exception:

> [__NSCFConstantString gtm_stringBySanitizingAndEscapingForXML]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x541f4

GTMNSString+XML.h is defined [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BXML.m).

What could the problem be?

Comment: Have you definitely `#import` ed the category header?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the include or import in order to get the functionality. 
You can verify by logging with respondsToSelector: